# How to read line to line when my txt is in the raw folder?

Tags: android

I have a txt in my raw folder with this text:

```
38.706937,-0.494406,Alcoy,Alcoy,Comunidad Valenciana
37.605651,-0.991294,Vuelo1,Cartagena,Región de Murcia
37.652022,-0.719147,Vuelo2,La Manga del Mar Menor,Región de Murcia
42.817988,-1.644183,Vuelo3,Pamplona,Navarra
36.750779,-5.812395,Vuelo4,Arcos de la frontera,Andalucia
```

And a method where I do this:

```
private void leerPuntosApp(){
    InputStream stream =getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sitios);
    BufferedReader brin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String todoPartes = null;

    try {
        while(brin.read() != -1){
            todoPartes = brin.readLine();
            dibujarPuntos(todoPartes);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void dibujarPuntos(String punto){
    Toast.makeText(this, punto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String []separados = punto.split(",");

        Dialog dialog = hacerDialogo(separados[0],separados[1],
                  separados[2],separados[3],separados[4]);

        itemOverlay = new CargarItem(puntosMapa,this,dialog);

        lat = Double.parseDouble(separados[0])*1E6;
        lon = Double.parseDouble(separados[1])*1E6;

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(),lon.intValue());
        //GeoPoint point = calcularCoordenadas(listaDeSitios.get(i).getCiudad());

        item = new OverlayItem(point,separados[2], null);
        itemOverlay.addOverlay(item);
        mapOverlays.add(itemOverlay);
        mapView.postInvalidate();

}
```

The strange thing is that the method dibujarPuntos just draw the first point but the toast shows me all the lines.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By doing the read() you are eating the first character of the line... are you sure the Toast was showing the correct data?

See if this helps

```
try {
    while((todoPartes = brin.readLine()) != null){
        dibujarPuntos(todoPartes);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And instead of using Toast for logging, just use `Log.d("MYTAG", punto)` and then check the LogCat output to see if it's parsing the information correctly.

Comment: Could you Log out the `saparados[0]` and see what it's value is, it should be `38.706...`  if the text has spaces before/after the comma, then you should change your `split()` to be `split("\\s*,\\s*")` so that the whitespaces get eaten.

Comment: I find the problem. If I do a substring of separados[0] like that separados[0].substring(1) the first point is painted well but the others lines are eaten the first characters. I dont understand happend this i wrote this and i see the txt and its correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's true read() eat my first character for the all the lines except the first. But if I do that you say I have a NumberFormatException in this line

```
lat = Double.parseDouble(separados[0])*1E6;
```

Comment: This should be added as a "comment" to my answer below (using the "add comment link)  (I responsded to this in the comments of my answers, below)